# Local development Django static files coming from library directory rather than my project

Tags: django, python-3.7, django-staticfiles, django-3.1

I have a Django (3.1) app that I've set up to serve static files, that is, `myapp/settings.py` has

```
DEBUG = True
```

.
.
.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    .
    .
    .
]
```

.
.
.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
```

But instead of serving files from the `static` directory of myapp, it's serving static files from `/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/`. I have tested this by adding files to both directories,

```
~/Projects/myapp/static/file-from-project.js
/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/file-from-library.js
```

and then

```
python3 manage.py runserver
```

with a template including the lines

```
<script src="{% static 'file-from-project.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'file-from-library.js' %}"></script>
```

and `file-from-library.js` loads fine but I get a 404 for `file-from-project.js`. What am I doing wrong here?

Directory structure with the referenced files:

```
myapp
  /myapp
    settings.py
    .
    .
    .
  /static
    file-from-project.js
    .
    .
    .
  /templates
    .
    .
    .
  manage.py
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: Where have you put `file-from-project`?

Comment: @michjnich In `~/Projects/myapp/static/file-from-project.js` and I'm running from the `~/Projects/myapp/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see the problem I think.

`STATIC_ROOT` is an absolute path, not a relative one. if you set it to eg. `BASE_DIR / "static"` you might get what you want.

I usually set `BASE_DIR` at the top of my `settings.py` as it gets used for a few things:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent
```

The other thing is that you have `DEBUG=True` which means it's going to be looking at your `STATIC_URL` under your app dirs. If you move the file to:

```
~/Projects/myapp/static/app_folder/file-from-project.js
```

It should work :)

Edit: I noticed `myapp` is an app, and not the project name, which makes me wonder what the project is called.

Your static files for development for this structure should probably be in:

```
~/Projects/myapp/static/myapp/<static file>
```

When you deploy, obviously `DEBUG` should be `False`, but here you should run `collectstatic` in order to gather all the static files in one place for deployment.

Comment: `BASE_DIR` is set that way by default, but moving to `~/Projects/myapp/myapp/static/file-from-project.js` didn't help. Or do you mean something different by `app_folder`?

Comment: Also, changing to `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')` doesn't have an effect on where things are getting pulled from.

Comment: I mean that in your path `myapp` is the name of your django project, then that project contains django apps, each potentially with its own static files.

Comment: Ah, wait, your app is `myapp` I see from `INSTALLED_APPS` . What is your django project called then? Not `Projects`??? Can you perhaps post your directory structure?

Comment: Added directory structure. Production is fine, I'm just having an issue with local development at the moment.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Sorry, use of `myapp` as the project name threw me off. Also I realise I put thewrong path in my answer - `(your root)/myapp/static/myapp/file-from-project.js` is probably what you want ... I corrected the error in the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234277/discussion-between-wogsland-and-michjnich).